# What is the most efficient way to find the relative XPath between two elements?

Tags: xml, perl, dom, xpath

Having looked at various popular modules for working with XML / XPath I have yet to see a straight-forward way to achieve this.

Essentially the interface would look something like:

```
my $xpath = get_path($node1, $node2);
```

...which would return the relative path from $node1 to $node2.

I include my own time in the calculation of 'efficiency' - I'll take any existing solution for this problem. Failing that, I'd like to know some of the pitfalls one might come up against in any 'obvious' home-grown solutions.

Off the top of my head I could imagine simply first searching for $node2 in $node1's descendants, then failing that iterate up $node1's ancestors doing the same thing. Would that be as raucously resource-intensive as I fear?

For my particular use-case, I can assume the absolute paths of both $node1 and $node2 are known. Given that, I would like to think there's some 'XPath math' that could be done between the two full paths without having to run about all over the tree, but I don't know what that process would look like.

*To summarise:*

1) Do any existing CPAN modules make what I want to do easy?

2) If not, what's an efficient way to go about it?

Comment: I am intrigued - it's an interesting intellectual exercise, but **why** do you want to do this?

Comment: I was careful not to include that ;) Don't get me wrong, I do fully appreciate when Perlfolk point out to me that the very question is wrong, but in this case I was pretty interested in the intellectual exercise, as you said.

Comment: (Ack... It's a little unintuitive that the textareas for comments submit immediately on <Enter> when those for the original questions do not. Anyway...)

The objective is to analyse a large number of websites using 'rules' along lines of, "if $node1 exists, grab the data in $node2". There may be multiple nodes matching the description of $node1 on a given page, at unpredictable points in the markup, but the target data can always be found in an element with a common relation to it, eg "2nd <li> child of the 1st enclosing <div>" or the like.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Find the absolute path for both nodes.

```
ref:    root foo bar[2] baz[1] moo
target: root foo bar[2] baz[2] moo
```

Remove common leading segments.

```
ref:    baz[1] moo
target: baz[2] moo
```

For each segment in the reference, prepend the target with a `..` segment.

```
.. .. baz[2] moo
```

Convert to XPath.

```
../../baz[2]/moo
```

---

Code:

```
use XML::LibXML qw( XML_ATTRIBUTE_NODE XML_ELEMENT_NODE );

sub get_path_segs {
   my ($node) = @_;
   my @path = split(/\//, $node->nodePath());
   shift(@path);
   return @path;
}

sub get_path {
   my ($ref, $targ) = @_;

   die if $ref->nodeType()  != XML_ELEMENT_NODE && $ref->nodeType()  != XML_ATTRIBUTE_NODE;
   die if $targ->nodeType() != XML_ELEMENT_NODE && $targ->nodeType() != XML_ATTRIBUTE_NODE;

   my @ref  = get_path_segs($ref);
   my @targ = get_path_segs($targ);

   while (@ref && @targ && $ref[0] eq $targ[0]) {
      shift(@ref);
      shift(@targ);
   }

   while (@ref) {
      pop(@ref);
      unshift(@targ, '..');
   }

   return @targ ? join('/', @targ) : '.';
}
```

It currently supports element and attribute nodes. It could be expanded to support other node types, possibly trivially.

Answer (score 2):

There are two possible outcomes

- the two nodes have a common ancestor
- one node is a descendant of the other

The logical course of action would be

- Traverse the parent nodes of each node and see if you find a common ancstor.
- While doing this, check if one of the ancestors is in fact *identical* to the other node.

In either case, the resulting path would be the shortest one.

Construct a relative XPath expression from the parent node chains. Finding an appealing representation might even be the hardest part of the entire problem.

Comment: Ah, much cleverer than my suggestion - and thank you for showing how you analysed the problem. I think ikegami's answer met the terms of my question the best, but your answer would be useful for working with *ML tree manipulation modules were XPath isn't available, eg `Mojo::DOM`. Will reply again if I come up with an elegant way of representing the relationship, although that will most likely be XPath- or module-dependant. Many thanks.